# Where could I find more propellant combustion charts for more different/more broad examples/numbers?

Tags: fuel, engine-design, combustion, combustion-chamber

So after asking how I could calculate [this kind of propellant combustion charts](http://www.braeunig.us/space/comb.htm) for different fuels/oxidizers and other ratios and other stuff and getting some really good answers, especially from [Anton Hengst](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/31429/anton-hengst) on the [post](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44669/how-to-calculate-these-engine-parameters-on-my-own), I got a bit overwhelmed.
So now I am asking you where I could find more of these precalculated charts.
For example, [Robert](http://www.watzlavick.com/robert/rocket/index.html) surely didn't use these charts as he had a different mixture ratio and maybe some other parameters as well. So where did he get his calculations/results?

Comment: A fair question, but I did edit the tags to better fit what is actually asked for in the question.